# Qunit trigger function does not work on JQuery DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, qunit

I try to trigger the onSelect function of a JQuery Datepicker with QUnit, but the event is never entered. Here is my sample code:

```
QUnit.test("Datepicker Test", function(assert) {
   var datepicker = $("#datepicker");

   var event = $.Event("onSelect");

   datepicker.on("onSelect"), function() {
       alert("Test");
   };

   // Trigger the key event
   datepicker.trigger(event);
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign the event handler you're closing the `on()` function call before actually passing in the event handler function. Try this instead:

```
datepicker.on("onSelect", function() {  // <-- removed the closing parenthesis after "onSelect"
    alert("Test");
});  // <-- notice the closing parenthesis here
```